# Ranged combat - warrior mage

Tags: combat, ranged-attack, tactics, rolemaster

#### Background

We're a group of four players new to Pen & Paper with a seasoned game master. Up to now we haven't had any active contact with magic skills during combats. Due to a mixture of bad tactical decisions on our end and dice rolls in favour of NPCs, another player and I died twice in four sessions. My new character is a warrior mage (not exactly sure on the translation, since our rules are in German), so now magic comes into the fray. The idea is to play as a ranged fighter with ideally two attacks per turn.

#### My question

Using a compound bow, "quicken" spells and maybe damage spells, how am I most useful to my companions while surviving the next battles?  How should I position myself, which distance should I keep, which targets should I pick, etc.

I know that this is more of a strategy question and might be a bit hard to answer.

I am trying to optimize combat effectiveness and survival.

---

If I remember right my new character knows the following tables:

- 237
- 241
- 48
- 19
- 20

Comment: Are you a warrior that bought spells? Or are you a ranger, possibly a dabbler? That will make a difference in possible answers. And yes, including the knowledge your character already has will help.

Comment: No, warrior mage is an actual profession introduced in Companion II. Tables incoming.

Comment: I'll take a look. I don't think we used that in our campaign, but I have played Rolemaster with one of the original authors as a GM. (Appeal to authority :p)

Comment: @BlackSpike: That seems like it should be an answer rather than a comment. As such, I have deleted. See this meta: [Should users refrain from answers (or partial answers) in comments?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments)

Comment: @Erik: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. I'm not personally familiar with Rolemaster, but this seems like it might be a primarily opinion-based question, which aren't really a good fit for the RPG.SE format; at the least, it seems a bit too broad, as you're asking for "tips for any combat situation". That said, you might be able to get more help refining the question (and perhaps get some answers) if you hop into the general [chat]. Hope you stick around! :)

Comment: My edit was mostly for format, and I think I have captured the focus of this question in the order that I placed what you are trying to optimize for.  Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast yeah, this quite captures it, thanks.

Comment: There are some users who are familiar with Rolemaster who drop by now and again, but it may be a few days before any of them spot this question. Best of luck.  My RM days are so far in the past that I am of no use to  you.