# Ranged combat in close quarters

Tags: ranged-attack, tactics, rolemaster

This is a more specified version of [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/151029/ranged-combat-warrior-mage).

Short background:

- I am rather new to Pen&Paper, thus my tactical knowledge is rather slim.
- Ranged attacks in Rolemaster are modified by distance and repetition,
  there's a penalty for firing during every round of battle, and also a
  penalty for distance, the further away the target, the less damage
  can be inflicted.
- PC/NPC and other objects most likely block the path of missiles, thus making ranged combat in close quarters difficult
- there are boni for flanking/rear attacks

I am seeking for ideas, how to best support my group against mobs in close quarters (aka dungeons) using a compound bow. Or should I go straight for my secondary, close-combat weapon?

Note: I naively assume that experiences from other P&P-rulesets can be translated.

Comment: I believe that modern English plural of "bonus" is "bonuses", unless that's not what you mean "boni" to be.

Comment: Though archaic - since Latin - "boni" is still correct ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I seem to remember that you had a -50 to attack if you fired into mêlée. This makes it quite likely to miss either target. The idea is that you are actively avoiding friendly fire. Combat Law should have the information you seek.

In close quarters areas, bows (including crossbows) are pretty much useless since you will either be engaged the same round as combat starts or will have to shoot into mêlée.  Note that open spaces, while underground, pose no such problem – for example, the Great Hall of Moria.